# How does DataParallel figure out which gpu I want to use?

Tags: pytorch

I want to find a simple way to specify the gpus that my experiments run on. Currently, I know I can use prepend my python command with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2,3,4 to set the gpu, and I am guessing DataParallel will then try to use all the gpu.

Is there a way to tell DataParallel directly the ids, like 4,7,9,12?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `DataParallem` provides us the feature of directly passing the gpu ids.

As per the official documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed), Data Parallelism is implemented using `torch.nn.DataParallel`. One can wrap a Module in `DataParallel` and it will be parallelized over multiple GPUs in the batch dimension.

```
torch.nn.DataParallel(module, device_ids=None, output_device=None, dim=0)
```

In your case, you can simply do something like this:

```
torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[4, 7, 9, 12])
output = net(input_var)  # input_var can be on any device, including CPU
```

You can know more about how to pass gpu ids directly to `DataParallel` in below links:

- [MULTI-GPU EXAMPLES](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html)
- [DataParallel layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#dataparallel-layers-multi-gpu-distributed)

Answer (score 0):

Using DataParallel you can specify which devices you want to use with the syntax:

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[ids_1,ids_2, ..., ids_n]).cuda()
```

When you use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES you're setting the GPU visible by your code.
For isntance, if you set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 and then execute:

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1]).cuda()
```

Using nvidia-smi you will see that your model will be running over GPU 2 and 3, as you set that specific ID as visible.